# My Linux System doesn't recognize hostname. How could I fix it?

Tags: linux, bash, service, hostname, hosts

I am setting a Linux machine and I have a problem. When I try to run the command:

```
hostname -f
```

I get this error:

```
hostname: Name or service not known
```

I am ew on this and I would like to know how could I solve it. My /etc/hosts and /etc/hostname files show the next:

/etc/hostname:

```
namehost
```

/etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

Thak you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt-get -f install` first and then retry.

Answer (score 0):

I had to configure the file /etc/hosts and add there the next line:

```
127.0.0.1    namehost
```

Doing this, it works!